# Finalization and promoting to generation1

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, finalization

my question is, i have objects in the generation 0, and i also overridden the finalization method.

When the gc collects the gen0, sees that it has to finalize to, so doesn't releases them immediatly, and promotes these objects to gen1? Therefore these will only be realeased if the gc collects gen1. **Assuming these objects will not be used again, they are garbage**

thanks!

Comment: This is something you should not concern yourself with. The GC does not guarantee that finalize will ever be called.

Comment: ok, but this is just for learning purposes

Answer (score 5):

> Finalize methods are called at the completion of a garbage collection on objects that the GC
>   has determined to be garbage. This means that the memory for these objects cannot be reclaimed
>   right away because the  Finalize method might execute code that accesses a field. Because a finaliz-
>   able object must survive the collection, it gets promoted to another generation, forcing the object
>   to live much longer than it should. Richter j. -CLR via C#

so yeah, it get's promoted :)